# Check if all images are loaded using unveil.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

Using [unveil.js](http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/)

I'm lazy loading 6 images on a page and I want to print the images on this page but I need to force a load of all the images first: Which is done with this:

```js
$("img").trigger("unveil");
```

I only want the print dialog to show up once all the images have been loaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$("img").trigger("unveil");` will cause all the images to be loaded, so printing you dialog right after that will output the dialog once they've been triggered.

Comment: yes but the dialog shows up before all the images have time to load.

Comment: If you're wanting to wait until a specific set of images has finished loading, you might want something like [this](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages).

Comment: actually, I think I figured it out: wrapping the last image in a on load function seems to do it.

Comment: The problem you might run into there is that if they last image (for whatever reason) loads quicker than the others, you'll still get the dialog before all the images have loaded.

Comment: hmmm, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with some jQuery and the `load` event:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

  var imageContainer = $('#imagecontainer');
  var numImages = $('img', imageContainer).length;
  var numImagesLoaded = 0;

  $('img', imageContainer).on('load', function() {
      numImagesLoaded++;
      if (numImagesLoaded == numImages) {
          runAfterAllImagesLoaded();
      }
  });

  function runAfterAllImagesLoaded()
  {
      alert('hello');
  }
});
```

Here's an example that uses [delay.me](http://www.deelay.me/) to load images in at random speeds and then displays an alert once they're loaded:

[(also a fiddle since the inline example doesn't show it that well)](https://jsfiddle.net/LLvc82u7/3/)

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

  var imageContainer = $('#imagecontainer');
  var numImages = $('img', imageContainer).length;
  var numImagesLoaded = 0;

  $('img', imageContainer).each(function() {
     var showtimetime = Math.floor(Math.random()*(5000-1000+1)+1000);
     $(this).attr('src', 'http://deelay.me/' + showtimetime + '/https://placekitten.com/400/200')
  });

  $('img', imageContainer).on('load', function() {
      numImagesLoaded++;
      if (numImagesLoaded == numImages) {
          runAfterAllImagesLoaded();
      }
  });

  function runAfterAllImagesLoaded()
  {
      alert('hello');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imagecontainer">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it doesn't seem to be working, even your fiddle doesn't work, it only loads two pics and never reaches the runAllImagesLoaded function. actually, in safari, it doesn't work, works in chrome.

Comment: Yup, this works, for some reason, it wasn't getting the correct numImages variable.  Thank you.